# python 3 indeterminate behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is the first time i see an indeterminate response of a computer program
to the same input, passed repeatedly, while not explicitly invoking any
randomness.

Consider the following python3 script, called strange.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

def main():
    opts_list=[['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b']] 
    opts_dict={}

    for pair in opts_list:
        opts_dict[pair[1]] = pair[0]

    print( opts_dict )
    return

main()
```

When the script, made executable, is run a  number of times from the shell as

```
$ ./strange.py
```

one sometimes gets {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, other times {'b': '2', 'a': '1'}. The bash sequence of commands below will run it 40 times and print the counts for each order observed:

```
$ rm -f tempfile ; for i in {1..40} ; do  ./strange.py >> tempfile ; done; echo "$( grep "a.*b" tempfile | wc -l ) a-b ordered pairs and $( grep "b.*a" tempfile | wc -l ) b-a ordered pairs in the 40 runs"
```

This seemed strange to me. The above behaviour is not observed in python 2 (just run the script with the python interpreter instead of python3), i noticed it as i translated an older script to python 3.

I am wondering if this is supposed to be so in python3, for some reason.

Comment: Not supposed to be, but is expected behavior. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python added hash randomization lately*

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0456/

It affects python3.4+ but can be enabled in older versions as well

To disable the feature (we caution!!!) set the enviorment variable PYTHONHASHSEED to some fixed value and your output will be the same every time

Comment: Alright, so there is no more constancy of behaviour, added to expected lack of order. Behaviour randomization added to code involving dictionaries through hidden/implied randomized hashing. Guess will have to sort the dictionary before usage or use OrderedDict instead (i was setting up regression testing against observed+approved output (implying unknown but fixed hashing scheme), and i saw it blow because of this new feature).

Comment: I've seen a few projects that assume repeatable (or deterministic) dict ordering. This is a wonderful change.

Comment: @FakeName - Since python3.6 - dicts are *ordered* by default (like **OrderedDict**) - so check it out